# Identifying Memory Leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-profiler, java-memory-leaks

I have [captured the heap dump](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#capture-heap-dump) using the Android Studio Memory Profiler. I know how to check the Leak Activity using the heap dump. I want to check memory leak Not in Activity only as my app contains less activity and most of the operations do not interact with the user my sample application.

Q. 1 How to check if there is MemoryLeak anywhere in code whose caller is not an activity.

Q2. Is MAT compulsory to analyze the Heap Dump?

Comment: You can use a library called [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to detect memory leaks.

Comment: @realpac , yes I am aware of this library. But I am looking the same, using the Android Studio Memory Profiler.